# Problem when using python logging in django and unicode

Tags: python, django, logging, unicode, decoding

totally confused by now... I am developing in python/django and using python logging. All of my app requires unicode and all my models have only a **unicode**()`, return u'..' methods implemented. Now when logging I have come upon a really strange issue that it took a long time to discover that I could reproduce it. I have tried both Py 2.5.5 and Py 2.6.4 and same thing. So

Whenever I do some straight forward logging like:

```
logging.debug(u'new value %s' % group)
```

this calls the models group.**unicode**(): return unicode(group.name)

My unicode methods all looks like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s - %s (%s)' % (self.group, self.user.get_full_name(), self.role)
```

This works even if group.name is XXX or ÄÄÄ (requiring unicode). But when I for some reason want to log a set, list, dictionary, django-query set and the individual instances in e.g. the list might be unicode or not I get into trouble...

So this will get me a UnicodeDecodingError whenever a group.name requires unicode like Luleå (my hometown)

```
logging.debug(u'new groups %s' % list_of_groups)
```

Typically I get an error like this:

```
Exception Type:     UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    ('ascii',  '<RBACInstanceRoleSet: s2 | \xc3\x84\xc3\x96\xc3\x96\xc3\x85\xc3\x85\xc3\x85 Gruppen>]', 106, 107, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

But if I do `print list_of_groups` everything gets out nice on terminal

So, my understanding is that the list starts to generate itself and does repr() on all its elements and they return their values - in this case it should be 's2 | ÅÄÖÖ', then the list presents itself as (ascii, the-stuff-in-the-list) and then when trying to Decode the *ascii* into unicode this will of course not work -- since one of the elements in the list has returened a u'...' of itself when repr was done on it.

But why is this????´

And why do things work and unicode/ascii is handled correctly whenever I log simple things like group.name and so or group and the **unicode** methods are called. Whenever I get lazy and want to log a list, set or other things go bad whenever a unicode character is encountered...

Some more examples that work and fail. If `group.name` I go to the model field and `group` calls the `__unicode__()`

```
    logging.debug("1. group: %s " % group.name) # WORKS
    logging.debug(u"2. group: %s " % group) # WORKS
    logging.debug("3. group: %s " % group) # FAILS
    logging.debug(u"4. group: %s " % group.name) # WORKS
    logging.debug("5. group: %s " % group.name) # WORKS
```

...and I really thought I had a grip on Unicode ;-(

Comment: oh, forgot. My production site uses postgres and I run sqllite for local testing/development but have same issue everywhere.

Comment: Do you have this problem only with the logging mechanism. What happens if you comment it?

Comment: yep - only logging. Printing the same stament is fine, comment away logging is fine. Noticed now that doing logging.debug(list_of_groups) shows nice logging message with unicode chars in it...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my test code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                      
class Wrap:                                          
    def __init__(self, s): self.s = s
    def __repr__(self): return repr(self.s)    
    def __unicode__(self): return unicode(self.s)
    def __str__(self): return str(self.s)

s = 'hello'  # a plaintext string
u = 'ÅÄÖÖ'.decode('utf-8') 
l = [s,u]
test0 = unicode(repr(l))
test1 = 'string %s' % l
test2 = u'unicode %s' % l
```

The above works fine when you run it.  However, if you change the declaration of **repr** to:
        def **repr**(self): return unicode(self.s)

Then it aborts with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 13, in <module> unicode(l)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3:
   ordinal not in range(128)
```

So it looks like someone in the object hierarchy has a repr() implementation which is incorrectly returning a unicode string instead of a normal string.  As someone else mentioned, when you do a format string like

```
'format %s' % mylist
```

and mylist is a sequence, python automatically calls repr() on it rather than unicode() (since there is no "correct" way to represent a list as a unicode string).

It may be django that's at fault here, or maybe you've implemented `__repr__` incorrectly in one of your models.

#

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem with a simple test:

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> group = u'Luleå'
>>> logging.warning('Group: %s', group)
WARNING:root:Group: Luleå
>>> logging.warning(u'Group: %s', group)
WARNING:root:Group: Luleå
>>>
```

So, as Daniel says, there is probably something which is not proper Unicode in what you're passing to logging.

Also, I don't know what handlers you're using, but make sure if there are file handlers that you explicitly specify the output encoding to use, and if there are stream handlers you also wrap any output stream which needs it with an encoding wrapper such as is provided by the `codecs` module (and pass the wrapped stream to logging).

Comment: yes, that works as you state. But my data is stored in django models and I work on those instances and when printing a group (i.e. instance of model class Group) with name, ... and lots of other field I just do print model -- this then calls the __unicode__ method of group to print or log itself. And this always works on instances. But when I have a list/set/dict of such instances and output them in debug.logging things crash if one of the instances returns unicode. Still, if there is not other way around this  I will go over all my logging statements and adapt them :-(

Comment: The key to me here is that when I do debug.loggin('%s' % list_of_groups), then the list when 'gathering itself' states that it is ascii, and then adds the individual elements given from repr(). Have tried to call repr() on individual elements of the list and then I get u'Luleå' and so on. If only the list could when 'gathering itself' figure out that it is not in ascii then it would not try and Decode itself into Unicode, since it already is, and I would not be having this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code in the top of your views.py

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what it is you don't understand, if you see what I mean. Your middle paragraph:

> So, my understanding is that the list starts to generate itself and does repr() on all its elements and they return their values - in this case it should be 's2 | ÅÄÖÖ', then the list presents itself as (ascii, the-stuff-in-the-list) and then when trying to Decode the ascii into unicode this will of course not work -- since one of the elements in the list has returened a u'...' of itself when repr was done on it.

explains exactly what is going on - outputting a list isn't the same as printing all its elements, because under the hood all it does is call repr() on each element in the list. Rather than outputting the raw list, you could log a list comprehension which calls unicode on each element, which would fix it.

Comment: yep - but I am sort of lazy and was hoping do be able to just output anything; lists, fields, .. and I have lots of code with warning/info/debug/error do go over and need to look at each statement and adapt if this is the case. Still if that is what it take then ...

Comment: Yes, there is another thing, first I simply tried to do:

logging.debug('new groups %s' % list_of_groups) # WORKS SUDDENLY

i.e. remove the u' and then lists/sets/dictionary all start to log great but then all my other statements where I log a field directly starts to fail with same error. So then e.g. would not work anymore:

logging.debug('new group with name %s' % group.name) # FAILS

Answer (score 0):

I ended following advice as answered and going over all code and doing list comprehension or similar when trying to log a set/list/dict/django queryset. So adapting and adding things like this solved it for me:

```
logging.debug(u"new groups: %s" % [unicode(g) for g in list_of_groups])
```

So now all I have to do is remember never ever to forget to do this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried manually making any result unicode?

```
logging.debug(u'new groups %s' % unicode(list_of_groups("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issues: see http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2012/09/unicode-quirks-in-django.html.

You can declare a **str**() method to override the Django default behavior, which will help to avoid this issue.  Or you always have to prefix the u' in front of your logging() statements.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
import locale
locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

must be 'utf8'. I have 'cp1252'.

Helped me add to manage.py:

```
import _locale
_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'utf8'])
```

Windows 10, Django 1.10.3, Python 3.5.2,
fixed problems with russian language

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this bug of Python is the reason of described behavior
https://bugs.python.org/issue19846
Check locale settings, if you getting UnicodeDecodeError on Python 3.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40803148/4862792 helps me for windows, but on production with locale LANG_C I`ve got this problem one more time

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow.com. Please be more precise about your answers, you can read about [how to write good answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)